# watch and move midi notes with p5js and react

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I want to move notes with p5js. I'am using createGraphics with p5Wrapper for reactjs, but I don't can not understand how to do this.
graph does not work... My goal is to move notes with midi file, I take back notes from midi file and draw it, after i want to move it...
Before i use pixijs but now i want to implement p5js

```
export default function sketch (p) {
    let height;
    let width;
    const numberOfWhiteKey = 43;
    let wWhiteNotes;
    let wBlackNotes;
    let y;
    let x;
    let h;
    let graph; 



    window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
                let pianoHeight =  document.getElementById("virtualPiano").clientHeight   
               let headerHeight =  document.getElementById('header').clientHeight

                    height = (window.innerHeight - pianoHeight - headerHeight)
                    width =  window.innerWidth
            })

    p.setup = function () {

        p.createCanvas(width, height);
        graph = p.createGraphics(width, height)
        console.log('TCL: p.setup -> this.graph', graph)
        p.image(graph,0,0, width, height)
        window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
            let pianoHeight =  document.getElementById("virtualPiano").clientHeight   
            let headerHeight =  document.getElementById('header').clientHeight

            height = (window.innerHeight - pianoHeight - headerHeight)
            width =  window.innerWidth

            p.resizeCanvas(width, height)
        })
        p.noLoop()
    };

    p.myCustomRedrawAccordingToNewPropsHandler = function (props) {

        if(props.x || props.y || props.h || props.wWhiteNotes|| props.wBlackNotes){
            x = props.x;
            y = props.y + height;
            h = props.h;
            wWhiteNotes = props.wWhiteNotes;
            wBlackNotes = props.wBlackNotes;

            graph.rect(x, y, wWhiteNotes, h);
            graph.rect(x, y,wBlackNotes, h);

        }



    };

    p.draw = function() {
        p.background(100);
        p.stroke(255);

        let ecartOctave = (width / numberOfWhiteKey) + (6*(width / numberOfWhiteKey))
            //Ecart entre chaque octave
        for(var i = ecartOctave ; i < width; i += ecartOctave) { 
            p.line(i,1000, i, 0) 
        }  



      };


  };
```

Comment: Sorry, just forgot to say hello and thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Either `myCustomRedrawAccordingToNewPropsHandler()` executes first and you try to use `rect()` on a undefined object or `setup()` executes first and `graph` is never updated/redrawn after drawing the rectangles on it. In both cases nothing would show on screen.

Comment: thank you for your lighting

Comment: How can I get y and redefine it with a new value ?